# Mercurial error with subrepos on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have critial problem with Mercurial configured with subrepos. When I try to commit or make update I get following error:

```
hg commit -m "commit" --traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 87, in _runcatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 679, in _dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 454, in runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 733, in _runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 687, in checkargs
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 676, in <lambda>
File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 385, in check
File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 1092, in commit
File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyc", line 1189, in commit
File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 1087, in commitfunc
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyc", line 955, in commit
File "mercurial\subrepo.pyc", line 847, in dirty
File "mercurial\subrepo.pyc", line 783, in _gitisbare
File "mercurial\subrepo.pyc", line 717, in _gitcommand
File "mercurial\subrepo.pyc", line 721, in _gitdir
File "mercurial\subrepo.pyc", line 737, in _gitnodir
File "subprocess.pyc", line 623, in __init__
File "subprocess.pyc", line 833, in _execute_child
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
abort: The system cannot find the file specified
```

My .hgsub:

```
webdriver/vendor/webdriver = [svn]http://php-webdriver-bindings.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/phpwebdriver/
app/vendor/bundles/Knp/Bundle/ZendCacheBundle = [git]http://github.com/knplabs/KnpZendCacheBundle.git
app/vendor/Zend/Cache = [git]http://github.com/knplabs/zend-cache.git
app/vendor/Zend/Filter = [git]http://github.com/knplabs/zend-filter.git
```

I use Windows XP and Mercurial 1.9.2. I have svn and git added to PATH and it works good.
When I try to update my subrepos manually there is no problem, svn up and git pull works good.

Comment: everything works fine on my teammates computers (they use Ubuntu).

Comment: It looks like it can't find git to run it and get the subrepo. I think it must be down to how and where you've added git and svn to your path.

Comment: I tried user env PATH and system env PATH. Still doesn't work :-/

Comment: when I removed git repos in .hgsub it worked. So problem is with git...

Answer (score 3):

If the [Git for Windows (mysysgit)](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) directory in your path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`, try changing it to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

This will enable git to work with Mercurial.

Comment: +1 had similar error (only without no message after `abort:` at all) and adding `bin` one to path fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To debug your path problem, you can use the following file

```
# qnddebug.py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

print os.environ['PATH']
print subprocess.call(['git', '--version'])
sys.exit(23)
```

and run it with `hg --config extensions.foo=qnddebug.py`. Then you see in the first line which path mercurial uses to find programs. The last line is error-code of the git call, and must be 0. Maybe there is the output of `git --version` in the line before the exit status, but this is a platform-specific detail.

Comment: This does not appear to work in the current version of TortoiseHg. Nothing is output.